# RegEx to match Json format

Tags: regex

I have regEx `\{\s*"lat"\s*:\s*(.+?)\s*,\s*"lng":\s*(.+?)\s*}` to match following JSON value `{"lat": 0.788,"lng":0.878798}`, but i want in such a way that it will only match if the "lat" and "lng" values are either integer or decimal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do that, you want to match `[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+` instead of `.*`

Although you probably want to parse that json to an object, since it is less error-prone (e.g., what if the order of long and lat is reversed?)

What language / framework are you using?

Answer (score 0):

```
^(0|[1-9][0-9]*|-[1-9][0-9]*)$
```